# How to Set `route` parameter and Load New Page

Tags: routes, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to pass in a `paper-button` value to the default router using the Polymer Shop App framework.  The `app-location` and `app-route` components are in both the App Shell and the Home Page.  I am not sure how to pass the data into the `route` object and refresh the view.

**App Shell**

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
  route="{{route}}"
  pattern="/:page"
  data="{{routeData}}"
  tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

<iron-pages role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" selected-attribute="visible">
  <shop-home name="home"></shop-home>
  <shop-detail name="detail"></shop-detail>
</iron-pages>
```

**Home Page**

```
<paper-button id="item" value="[[item.name]]" on-tap="viewItem">[[item.name]]</paper-button>

...

viewItem() {
  this.route.path = '/detail';
  this.routeData = '/inventory/' + this.$.item.value;
}
```

P.S.

```
<a href$="/detail/inventory/[[item.name]]"> successfully redirects to the `detail` page and loads the data.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass the data to the route object, wrap `a tag` the item instead of a button element, At below example I didn't try to convert your all code to this. just I tried to explain what I meant: (Note: I was working on this subject for 2-3 weeks for an app, it works nicely now.) I will try to add a demo while.

```
<a href="/detail/inventory/[[item.name]]"><div>[[item.name]]</div></a>
```

instead of:

```
 <paper-button id="item" value="[[item.name]]" on-tap="viewItem">[[item.name]]</paper-button>
```